# sql server connection error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, connection

I keep getting the following error when I try to register a db server:

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to p3swhsql-v14.shr.phx3.secureserver.net.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.  When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

I googled, but most of the solutions are related to checking stuff on the sql server. It
s a shared server and I don't have access to the machine. I tried to register another db server and I get the same error. I know the connection properties are correct. I am not sure what else I can do. Btw, the windows firewall on my local machine is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If the server isn't set up to receive remote connections and you can't edit the server, I'm not sure that there's much you can do. You can't connect to a remote database if it doesn't want you to, and for good reason.

Many times, you can also be limited to just one IP or range of IPs, so it won't work from multiple locations. Again, this is something to set on the server, so you'd need to check with your provider.

Comment: Actually, it's setup to receive remote connections. I don't have these issues from my home computer.

Comment: On the server, it's very easy to limit remote connections for a user to just one or a few IPs. You need to check with your provider for this. It's bad practice to open your machine up to the world, even if it allows remote connections--so your provider is at least practicing safe sysadmining. =)

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar thread with some suggestions at: [Getting a sql connection error when trying to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846479/getting-a-sql-connection-error-when-trying-to-login).

Other possible issues could be a firewall on the server side that is only allowing connections from a certain IP range.  Even if your own firewall is off, that doesn't mean the server's firewall is letting your machine through.  Did the server admin open up a hole for your home machine?

Comment: What I meant was I was able to register the dB from my home computer. There are no policies to let my home computer in. It got something to do with a firewall or something running on my work computer.

Answer (score 1):

This error was due to the office firewall. If I connect to another VPN, everything works fine. Whilst doing research on google, I came across something perhaps it could be useful to somebody else.Go to the registry editor:
HKEY_Local_Machine > software > Microsoft > MSSQLServer > Client > SuperSocketNetLib . The protocolOrder in my instance was set to start with np tcp and so on. You can modify the order so that tcp :: port 1433 is used before trying to connect via named pipes.'

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link.
It was very helpfull. Just follow few steps and u will get to know the solution

http://techpint.com/programming/error-26-%E2%80%93-error-locating-serverinstance-specified-sql-server